# Laravel - JQuery Evento preventDefault não está permitindo inserir os registros no banco?

Tags: laravel

Utilizei o seguinte código `JQuery` para evitar o recarregamento da página ao inserir um registro no banco. realmente parou de recarregar, porém não está permitindo gravar os registros no banco.

```
$( "#btnAtividades" ).click(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
});
```

me disseram que tenho que por mais alguma coisa após o evento, porém ninguém me explica exatamente o que achei uns exemplos porém era em PHP puro e eu estou utilizando Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

O `preventDefault` faz com que seja bloqueado o comportamento padrão do evento atual, no seu caso o evento *click*, ou seja, se você bloqueia o evento clique do botão que faz o submit do seu form para o Laravel, esse form nunca é enviado.

Segundo o MDN, `Event.preventDefault()`:

> Cancela o evento se for cancelável, sem parar a propagação do mesmo.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Se você deseja inserir esses dados no Laravel sem que a página seja recarregada, você pode enviar via ajax com um método `POST` e fazer com que seu controller retorne uma http response de sucesso (200) ou de algum erro caso ocorra.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/